# Nested Case When DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I understand nested Case statements well enough but my question is if you can do one with a list. My example:

```
case when column in ('A','B','C') then '1'
when column in ('X','Y','Z') then '2'
else column end as New_val
```

I tried it this way or with this thinking and its not working and I can't find anything online that specifically relates to this.

Comment: Your `case` expression is fine.

Comment: The case is fine and will work in DB2. What is the problem or error message?

Answer (score -1):

Your `case` expression is fine.  I think the issue with `case` and `in` comes up in the context of using `case` in a `where` clause:

```
where column in (case when cola = 'a' then (1, 2, 3)
                      else (4)
                 end)
```

This is not allowed.  A `case` expression returns a scalar value, not a list of values.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense showing what doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher . . . The OP is clearly confused about `case` and `in`.  This is the most common form of confusion that I encounter.